# When I use kivy on QPython it gives segmentation fault

Tags: kivy, qpython

I am using QPython to run python on Android although it successfully import kivy module but it gives segmentation fault  when I run it

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Comment: I suffering to make pongGame on kivy tutorials to work on my phone,  the problem with. kv file although it is the same as published on website

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You just have to add these lines of code above your actual code (in your main.py file) :

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy
```

I hope I could help.